# Vuejs Variable Assign Error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-resource

This error is my title and i'm using a combination of VueJs, Vue-Resourse and Laravel.

The error happens when i try assigning 1 local variable to response data that i get back from sending an AJAX request using vue-resource.

**Code**

**Javascript**

```
<script>
        flags_page = new Vue({

            el: '#body',

            data: {
                retrievedFlags: {},
                chosenFlag: ''
            },

            ready: function () {
                this.getFlagTypes();
            },
            methods: {
                getFlagTypes: function(){

                    this.$http.get('/getFlags=' + '{{ $id }}', function(data){

                        //Problem with this line
                        this.retrievedFlags = data.retrievedFlags;

                    })
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

**PHP**

```
public function getFlags($type)
   {
    $flags       = Flags::all();

    return [
        'retrievedFlags' => $flags,
        'chosenFlag' => $type,
    ];
}
```

**ERROR**

```
vue.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at new n (vue.min.js:7)
    at r._bind (vue.min.js:8)
    at n (vue.min.js:6)
    at vue.min.js:6
    at new n (vue.min.js:6)
    at n.create (vue.min.js:6)
    at r.create (vue.min.js:6)
    at r.diff (vue.min.js:6)
    at r.update (vue.min.js:6)
    at n.update._update (vue.min.js:8)
```

Again i'm not sure whats causing this I've changed so many things around and i get the same error still. I find this strange because i have other pages that do the exact same things but for some reason this ones throwing up an error.

Its worth nothing that when i `console.log()` the data object that is returned it shows the data perfectly fine, but the moment i try to assign it to a variable it throws the error.

I also have vuejs included locally along with vue-resource.

Image of me console.logging(this): https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaAvR.jpg

Comment: Did you install VueResource?

Comment: Actually, it seems the error occurs when `get` from `$http` is called. `$http` doesn't seem to defined. Can you provide the code where you configure VueResource?

Comment: @Bert I have it saved locally in the public/js folder. Its located in my app.blade.php template which i extend on the page that i use the JS.

Comment: Have you registered Vue Resource as plugin ? `Vue.use()`

Comment: `'/getFlags=' + '{{ $id }}'` doesn't look right. I'd expect `'/getFlags/' + '{{ $id }}'` 
 which would hit the `getFlags` route with `{type} = $id`

Comment: @apokryfos This is working like i said its returned the data variable and i can console.log it, and get the correct data displayed. The problem is when i go to assign the returned data to a variable

Comment: @BelminBedak Ive never come across this before? The entirety of the app uses the method i use to get things done. And also if Vue wasnt registered then how come i am able to make requests with it and get data back?

Comment: The error you posted indicates that `this.$http` is undefined. That's why we are asking about VueResource. Are you using something else other than VueResource that sets `this.$http`?

Comment: @Bert Just double checked and im not using anything else, in fact ive included the version of vuejs im using on the page and its thrown a different error saying i cannot redefine $url

Comment: It would be useful to know the context which `getFlagTypes` gets called in. Perhaps `this` is not what you'd expect. Try a `console.log(this)` before the `this.$http.get`

Comment: Looks like you are using Vue 1? If so I don't know what version of VueResource you are using, but newer versions bind the callback to the Vue. Your version *may* not, so you might try just changing your callback to an arrow function (`this.$http.get('/getFlags...', data => {...})`). But the error still indicates $http doesn't even exist as a property on your Vue which means it wasn't properly installed.

Comment: @apokryfos Ive added an image of the result of a console.log of `this` before `this.$http.get`

Comment: @Bert Ive tried that code and i get the same result, didnt know i could use JS like that though thanks.

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work (though the vue instance doesn't have a `$http` object on it. Does using `Vue.http.get` instead work?

Comment: @apokryfos I have found the error, ill make an answer so let me know what you think because it seems to me like its almost unrelated, especially with the information it was sending back.

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution**

Changing this line of code `:checked="{flag.name == chosenFlag}"` to this `:checked="flag.name == chosenFlag"`

**The Explanation**

So the error was not in any of the code that i gave out, although the error was triggered by me trying to assign a variable after making an ajax request using Vue-Resource it wasnt the actual source of the error.

After @apokryfos asked me to `console.log(this)` before my `this.$http.get` function i decided to do it again afterwards and found that the data was infact being set, as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjRqw.jpg

So i then went to my code that renders the data in HTML and commented it out to see what was wrong and it worked.. no error. This was the code i was using to render the HTML.

```
<div class="mt-checkbox-inline">
    <div class="col-md-1" v-for="flag in retrievedFlags">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" :checked="{flag.name == chosenFlag}" value="@{{ flag.name }}"> @{{ flag.name }}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The solution to this error was to remove the curly braces from the `:checked=""` attribute. I used the curly braces because the vuejs documentation showed that it was what was needed to be used, but it was the source of the problem. I think my vuejs version was the reason behind this which also probably misled anyone trying to help.